# user- or group based DNS resolution settings

Tags: linux, dns

Can I change DNS resolution settings on a per-group or per-user basis on Linux 3.x?

I would like different groups to use different DNS servers and (if possible) different static entries (like those in /etc/hosts). Is there a way to configure this?

Comment: Namespaces could (conceivably) solve both of those, though it would be non-trivial.

Comment: You can do this if your users and groups are in well-partitioned IP address ranges ("split DNS") but I can't see a way of doing this per user/group on a single machine.

Comment: There's just too many places where the lines blur on a single machine - one of these is the DNS cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not trivially. Your DNS configuration underpins a lot of things with your system, and so context switching name resolution gets messy fast.

Imagine if you will - I send an email. I 'send' the mail to a particular remote server (resolved against my version of DNS) and it gets there.

But then I do the same, and pipe it to `mail` and `localhost` figures out where to relay it based on it's own mail exchange records.

The best you could do is virtualise and set up 'group' servers with specific DNS configs.